# Start Quartz Job dynamically in ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, quartz.net

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API and have chosen to use Quartz.net to execute recurring tasks.

I've implemented the `QuartzHostedService` as recommended and I manage to start job successfully by declaring them in the startup.

But I also need to add and execute some jobs dynamically by getting them in a database, and I don't want to deploy and restart my Web API each time I need to add a new recurring job (because some of my clients could add their own recurring tasks).

I managed to add jobs in the quartzHosted service by implemented a method in it:

```
public async Task AddJob(JobSchedule job)
{
        Scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

        Scheduler.JobFactory = _jobFactory;
        var j = CreateJob(job);
        var trigger = CreateTrigger(job);
        await Scheduler.ScheduleJob(j, trigger);
        job.JobStatus = JobStatus.Scheduling;

        await Scheduler.Start();
        job.JobStatus = JobStatus.Running;
}
```

I have implemented an `InitialJob` that have the goal to ask the database for new jobs (this job is declared in the startup).

In this `InitialJob`, my execute method is like this:

```
// Create a new scope
using (var scope = _provider.CreateScope())
{
    // Resolve the Scoped service
    var _uow = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
    var stats = await _uow.Stat.GetActive();

    var test = await _quartzHostedService.GetAllJobs();

    foreach (var clientStat in stats.GroupBy(s => s.Clients))
    {
        foreach (var job in clientStat)
        {
            var key = new JobKey($"{job.Constant}.{clientStat.Key.FirstOrDefault().Id}");
            var jobExist = _quartzHostedService.Scheduler.CheckExists(key);

            if (!jobExist.Result)
            {
                var jobSchedule = new JobSchedule(jobType: typeof(GenericSimulationJob), cronExpression: job.Trigger.CronTask, job, clientStat.Key.FirstOrDefault().Id);
                await _quartzHostedService.AddJob(jobSchedule);
            }
        }
    }

    var test2 = await _quartzHostedService.GetAllJobs();
}
```

When I check the jobs before adding them (variable test) I only have 2 jobs in the quartzHostedService, after adding them in the foreach (variable test2) I have 5. Perfect.

But it seems I'm not able to execute them. I only see 2 jobs in my QuartzHostedService.Schedule.CurrentlyExecutedJob.

I also see only 2 jobs in my jobFactory variable.

I tried to sleep and restart my Schedule but nothing works. Did I missed something? Is it just possible?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I forgot to declare my IJob (which contains my scheduleJobs) in the startup, even if there is no job schedule in it at start.

```
services.AddSingleton<GenericSimulationJob>();
```

Then my code works (without start scheduler instance again).